# Clearing the cookie programmatically

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have a login page called `signin.php` where a user can enter an email and password. On clicking submit button, page directs to `connection_validate.php`. This page validates the user entered data with database. If it's a registered user, the page directs to `calendar.php`. If the entered data is incorrect, it should redirect to `signin.php`. If the entered data is incorrect, I have placed cookie like this:

```
//action to be done if e mail id and password matches with database records             
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    header('location:calendar.php');
}
//action to be done if e mail id and password does not matches with database records 
else
{
    setcookie('message','incorrect login data');
    header('location:signin.php');
}
```

In signin.php, I have written the code for displaying an alert if login information is incorrect like this:

```
<?php
include("include/minfooter.php"); 
if(isset($_COOKIE["message"]))
{
    if(!($_COOKIE["message"]==" "))
    {
        echo "<script>
    alert('Incorrect login information');
    </script>";
    setcookie("message"," ",time()-3600);
    }
}
?>
```

My issue is that alert is displaying each time when I load the signin page if I have entered a error login data once. If I press the back button from the calendar.php to signin.php also, alert starts showing. I understood that the problem is with cookie. Cookie has not been removed. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your signin.php as follows

```
<?php
    include("include/minfooter.php");
    if (isset($_COOKIE["message"]))
    {

        echo "<script>
                var delete_cookie = function(name) {
                    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
                };
                var msg = '" . $_COOKIE["message"] . "';
                if (msg != '')
                    alert('Incorrect login information');
                delete_cookie('message');
            </script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is wrong, setcookie() sets an HTTP header which CAN NOT be put after you have already output content to the browser. Also your syntax is all wrong.

Comment: I'd say 75% correct. You have if(isset($_COOKIE["message"])) twice, it's still not the correct approach though.

Comment: better, but not the correct way to do what OP is wanting. OP wants to show login error, which means they are creating a login session which is exactly what $_SESSION variables are for. No javascript needed, no additional cookies, all just simple PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a session you can use the $_SESSION variable instead of a cookie value. Also you can not use setcookie() AFTER you have output content since setcookie() will send an HTTP header which must be sent prior to any content being sent.

```
session_start();
//action to be done if email id and password matches with database records
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    header('Location: calendar.php');
    exit;
}
//action to be done if email id and password does not matches with database records
else
{
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'incorrect login data';
    header('Location: signin.php');
    exit;
}
```

Then:

```
<?php

session_start();
include("include/minfooter.php"); 

if (!empty($_SESSION['message']))
{
    echo "<script>alert('" . $_SESSION["message"] . "');</script>";
    $_SESSION['message'] = '';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe is better to use session for that use a index ['messages'] on the $_SESSION array, then cleanup, the cookie should be used when you want reference some info after the user get out of your page. I made your code on using cookies, but consider using session:

```
<?php include("include/minfooter.php"); 
        if(isset($_COOKIE["message"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["message"])
        {
                echo "<script>
                    var msg = '<?php echo $_COOKIE["message"];?>';
                    if (msg != "")
                    alert('Incorrect login information');
                  </script>";
              unset($_COOKIE["message"]);
        }
?>
```